# How do I compute the integral over a submanifold?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, submanifold

I have the following problem:

> I need to compute $\int_M f(x) dS(x)$ where $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}$ and $M=\{(x,y,z):z=xy, x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$

I wanted to use the formula for an integral over a submanifold, but then I don't know if I need to write $M$ as a union of disjoint sets $M_i$ or not. Furthermore I don't see how to find a chart in this situation. I thought using polar coordinates, but this somehow doesn't give me the same set.

In the meantime we found a chart, namely $$\phi(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta,r^2\cos\theta \sin\theta)$$

Now I wanted to compute the gram determinant therefore I first need to compute the gram matrix: for that one I got
\begin{align}
\langle v,v\rangle &=1+r^2\sin^2(2\theta),\\
 \langle v,w\rangle =\langle w,v\rangle &=\frac{r^3}{2}\cos(4\theta),\\ 
\langle w,w\rangle &=r^2+r^4\cos^2(2\theta)
\end{align}
but I'm not sure if this is correct because it seems to me really ugly

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please show your effort. The surface is $z = xy$ with given bounds which tells you that its projection in xy-plane is a unit disk.

Comment: so can i take $$\phi:(0,1)\times (0,2\pi)\rightarrow M, \phi(r,\theta)=(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta),r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$$?

Comment: First of all you have you observe that your set is a Manifold with Boundary and so you have to quote this theorem that you can found in the text Analysis on Manifolds by James Munkres.

Comment: Let be $f\Bbb R^{n+k}\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ of calss $C^r$. Let $M$ be the set of all $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. Assume that $M$ is non-empty and that $Df(x)$ has rank $n$ for $x\in M$. Then $M$ is a $k-manifold$ without boundary in $\Bbb R^{n+k}$. Furhtermore, if $N$ is the set of all $x$ for which 
$$
f_1(x)=\dots=f_{n+1}(x)=0\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,f_n(x)\ge 0
$$
and if the matrix 
$$
\partial f_1,\dots,\partial f_(n-1)/\partial x
$$
has rank $(n-1)$ at each point of $N$ then $N$ is a $k+$ manifold and $\partial N= M$.

Comment: Then a possible solution is to observe that the interior of $N$ in your particular case is covered by a single coordinate chart that you have naturally find and so use the following theorem which you can fin in the Munkres text.

Comment: would my chart from above work

Comment: @Wave yes that is correct

Comment: Let $M$ be a compact $k$-manifold in $\Bbb R^n$ of class $C^r$. Let $f\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be a continuous function. suppose that $\alpha_i:A_i\rightarrow M_i$ for $i=1,\dots,h$ is a coordinate patch on $M$ such that $A_i$ is open in $\Bbb R^k$ and $M$ is the disjoint union of the open sets $M_1,\dots,M_h$ of $M$ and a set $K$ of measure zero in $M$. Then 
$$
\int_M f=\sum_{i=1}^h\int_{A_i}(f\circ \alpha_i)V(D\alpha_i)
$$
where V is the volume function.

Comment: @MathLover thank you. but is it true that the gram matrix looks really ugly?

Comment: @Wave I think to agree with MathLover.

Comment: No the gram matrix is not that ugly (I mean 'ugly' is relative :) so I am telling from my perspective). Also the integral simplifies quite a bit once you find the gram matrix. Please try and if you get stuck or want to validate your work, ping.

Comment: I somehow get really ugly stuff. So we learned that we first compute $d\phi$ and then denote the first column v and the second one w. then the gram matrix is $$\left(\begin{array}{rrr} <v,v>&<v,w>\\<w,v>&<w,w>\end{array}\right)$$ but this is not nice in my computations

Comment: Yes that is right. Please add your work to the question and what you get. I will look at it.

Comment: so I get $$<v,w>=<w,v>=\frac{r^3}{2}\cos(4\theta), <v,v>=1+r^2\sin^2(2\theta), <w,w>=r^2+r^4\cos^2(2\theta)$$

Comment: @Wave you have been here for a while and you know that all of] your thoughts and work / progess must be included as context when you are asking a question. As your question stands right now, it is likely to get closed.

Comment: oh sorry so I will ad more informations. I added all my progress now, but I still do not know why my gram matrix is wrong

Comment: The new information you added is already given to you (by Math Lover) in their previous answer to you [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4312344/629362).

Comment: I see, to be honest I forgot about this one thank you!

Comment: @wave your mistake is in the calculation of $\langle v,w\rangle$ and $\langle w,v\rangle$. It should be $ \frac{r^3}{2} \sin 4\theta$. Please check where you made a mistake. Rest is fine and you will get the result $r \sqrt{1 + r^2}$

Comment: @MathLover. Yes I found the mistake, I had some typo in my solution thank you!